# mysql date is different when print from php

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I have field with type (timestamp) and default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, the date is correct when I browsing records with phpMyAdmin but when I tried to display it by PHP file it displayed incorrect date

date in MySQL 2017-07-05 10:28:12

date in PHP 2017-06-23 09:51:31

using below query

```
SELECT u.date FROM table u
```

the global time zone of MySQL server is (SYSTEM) and I didn't change

PHP code

```
<?php
include("../config.php");
$sql = mysql_query("sql query");
var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($sql));
?>
```

Any support?

**SOLUTION**

If you face this problem you have to do the following:

Instead of mysql use PDO or mysqli_* functions and this will solve the problem without setting timezones either in your MySQL server or PHP files.

Comment: I suspect PhpMyAdmin is doing the conversion, because PHP doesn't do that by itself.

Comment: You're missing something. Can you post your php code ?

Comment: @Prabhat G check the code please

Comment: @PrabhatG looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some other issue (more to the code 'picture', perhaps? ... or some other config/setting?), as I cannot reproduce.

Here's my sample data:

[image]

Here's the structure for the `date` column:

[image]

The PHP code that I used:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test';

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'xxxxx');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT t.date FROM tryme t");
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

...and the output: (**note that I used PDO handling in the above PHP code, the output would be similar if mysqli was used**)

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-05 14:45:51"
    [0]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-05 14:45:51"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-05 14:45:51"
    [0]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-05 14:45:51"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-05 14:45:51"
    [0]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-05 14:45:51"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-05 14:45:51"
    [0]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-05 14:45:51"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-05 14:45:51"
    [0]=>
    string(19) "2017-07-05 14:45:51"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Example mysqli code, instead of PDO, to achieve the same output:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'xxxxx', 'test');
$result = $db->query("SELECT t.date FROM tryme t");

$rows = [];

while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() ) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

var_dump($rows);
```

Comment: it is working fine, what is the problem with mysql function if I want to use it instead of PDO !

Comment: The mysql_* functions are considered deprecated, and should no longer be used. However, the mysql**i**_* can be used instead of PDO. Using mysqli should give the same results as my output.

Comment: Thanks alot, got it now +1

Comment: So what did you do differently, for others that might cross this answer?

Comment: I amend the subject and adding the solution